# Jquery returns b.fn.b.init[102]

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, web

I have to select multiple elements, all them have the class ="org-box". Inside that box there is a link a that I want to capture the href. So I do this

```
$("a.org-box").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var link = $(e).html();
 $('.col-right').prepend("<b>" + link +"</b>");
})
```

What I always get is null, and I have tried other selectors like
    var link = $(e.a).attr("href").html();

With the same luck.

I checked what I get from that selection `$("a.org-box")` and I get this -> b.fn.b.init[102]

If I do this `$("a.org-box:first").attr("href");` I get correctly the href, but when I do `$("a.org-box").attr("href");` I just get the first one.

What Im doing bad ?? How to select all the a.org-box and capture href on click ?

Comment: /facepalm Do people not read documentation anymore? http://api.jquery.com/click/ Says you get the eventObject as a parameter

Comment: Which browser are you using? the jQuery factory function (`jQuery` or `$`) returns `jQuery.fn.init`, but because they're sourced from minified code the name will show up as `b.fn.b.init`.

Comment: dam $(this) solved it.... thx alot and sorry for be so noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="org-box">Click to prepend Google</a>
```

--

```
$("a.org-box").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.col-right').prepend("<b>" + e.target.href +"</b>"); //http://google.com
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gX7w7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$("a.org-box").click(function (e) {
    $('.col-right').prepend('<b>' + $(this).attr('href') + '<b>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`this` is set to `e.target`, with `e.target` being the *target* of the *event* (the item that was clicked on). You can use `$(this).attr('href')`, `$(this).prop('href')`, `this.href`, or any of the same variants using `e.target`.

<sub>I can't tell is whether you need the inner text (`.text()`) of the link, or the `href` attribute, so I'm assuming the latter.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors return ALL matched elements, so what's happening is you're getting the jQuery collection of those elements back from the selector, the event data is NOT the element that triggered the event a correct implementation would be:

```
$(a.org-box).click(function(){
    var link = $(this).html();
    $('.col-right').prepend("<b>" + link +"</b>");
});
```

you use `$(this)` because jQuery is iterating over the collection so just like if you were using `.each()` the `this` object holds your element.