# jQuery .click +..+ notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to understand a codrops [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/11/14/animated-portfolio-gallery/). Its essentially a slider with a thumb scroller.

I reached a point in the code where they were setting variables to represent clicked items in the thumb scroller like this.

```
 var $currentTitle       = $pg_title.find('h1:nth-child('+(current+1)+')');

 var $nextTitle          = $pg_title.find('h1:nth-child('+(idx+1)+')');

 var $currentThumb       = $pg_preview.find('img.pg_thumb:eq('+current+')');
```

I have never seen notation like this `+....+`. I have been digging and found examples where people used it in stack like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012492/jquery-returns-b-fn-b-init102) but I haven't seen anyone explain it could someone explain how `+...+` returns the value of the clicked item?

Comment: it is the simple string concatenation

Comment: If you look closely, they're using string concatenation to build a selector.

Comment: `'h1:nth-child('+(current+1)+')'`: creates a string like `h1:nth-child(2)` where current = 1

Comment: I apologize for this I missed the ball here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used with a string operand, it concatenates the two strings. In this case, to create a selector. When used with a number, it works as an addition operator. It is used in both ways here. So, if `current == 1`, 
`h1:nth-child('+(current+1)+')`' will evaluate first to `h1:nth-child('+2+')`, which will ultimately evaluate to `h1:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 0):

'+' Use for string **concatenation**

```
$pg_title.find('h1:nth-child('+(current+1)+')');
```

Like:

```
var b = 'def';
```

If you want to add some other string in 'b' variable then you can use '+' for concatenation

```
var addSomotherSting ='abc' +  b  + 'ghi'; 

alert(addSomotherSting);
```

Then browser show a alert box with **'addSomotherSting'** the out put is : **'abcdefghi'**